# Why does the American Express credit application ask how you want your name to appear?

Tags: canada, credit-card

On the Canadian credit application for an Amex card after it asks for your full name it asks next: how do you want your name to appear on the card? I don't remember Visa asking this. Does this mean we can choose a nickname of our choice?  It does say the FULL last name must appear though.

Answer (score 4):

It's for a preferred name. For example, my given name is 'Daniel' but I prefer to be called 'Dan'.

Your first name on a debit/credit card isn't important which is why they ask you for your actual surname... but that doesn't mean you're allowed to make up a first name like Superman, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, so short forms of your original first name only?  Not like "Jane" instead of "Anne"?...

Comment: Haha, yeah. As I say, the first name's not important so you could try getting 'Jane' instead of 'Anne' if you like. I once had 'Captain Wow' on a store card and they busted me for it because it made me ineligible to claim the cashback/rewards... so I'd go for a *real* preferred name for an Amex Card - just in case!